# React Switching Menu Styles based on Window Width

Tags: reactjs, resize, conditional-rendering

I have a navigation menu that works nicely in two different layouts. On a smaller screen (mobile) we have a dropdown that opens over the header. On bigger screens, the items are offered next to each other across the top. I want to ensure the display updates between the two on resize. At the moment, if the user resizes from mobile-width to more, the menu items just disappear, unless the dropdown is left open (i.e. the IsActive boolean is set to true).

I am working in React (JSX), so the previous approach of having a js file that switches between CSS classes doesn't work nicely. I've thus switched to conditional rendering. I've read I should avoid forcing a re-render. Is there another way, or do I have to bite the bullet in this scenario?

Many thanks in advance for any help and pointers on best practices and solutions.

My current code:

Navigation.jsx:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, Suspense} from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import navStyle from "../styles/Navigation.module.scss";
import {useTranslation} from "react-i18next";

function getWindowSize() {
    const {innerWidth, innerHeight} = window;
    return {innerWidth, innerHeight};
  }

function HeaderComponent() {
   (…)

  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const menuClick = () => {
    if(windowSize >= 750) {
        setIsActive(true);
    }
    // toggle
    setIsActive(current => !current);
  };

  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState(getWindowSize());

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleWindowResize() {
      setWindowSize(getWindowSize());
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);
    };
  }, []);

    return <header>
<div>

    <nav>
    (…)
        <div id={navStyle.menu}>
            <button id={navStyle.menulink} onClick={menuClick}>Menu</button>
            {(isActive && (
                <ul id={navStyle.navlinks}>
                <li><NavLink to="/" >Home</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="about" >About</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="examples" >Examples</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="reviews" >Reviews</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="contact" >Contact</NavLink></li>
            </ul>
            )}
            
        </div>
    </nav>
    (…)
</div>
</header>
}

function Navigation() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback="loading">
            <div className="App">
                <HeaderComponent/>
            </div>
        </Suspense>
  );
}

export default Navigation;
```

Navigation.module.scss:

```
@use "../styles/mixin.scss" as mixin;

/* MENU & NAVLINKS*/
.menu {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
}
#menulink {
     background-color: mixin.$primary-color;
     margin: 0;
     color: mixin.$secondary-color;
     text-align: center;
     & a {
        color: mixin.$secondary-color;
        font-size: 1em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 200;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: source-sans-pro;
        font-style: normal;
    } 
    @include mixin.non-mobile {
        display: none;
    }
}
  #navlinks {
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: mixin.$black;
    background-color: rgba(0, 26, 51, 0.65);
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: 400;
    & a {
         display: block;
         padding: 10px 0;
         color: mixin.$secondary-color;
         font-weight: 400;
         text-decoration: none;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         &:hover, &:active, &:focus, &.thispage {
             color: mixin.$secondary-highlight;
            }
        }
        @include mixin.non-mobile {
            max-width: 1000px;
            position: static;
            &.collapsed {
                opacity: 1;
            }
            & a {
                width: 15%;
                padding-top: 15 0;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
                float: left;
                font-weight: 700;
                &:hover, &:active, &:focus, &.thispage {
                    font-size: 18px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    (…)
```

mixin.scss

```
$primary-color: #001A33;
$primary-highlight: #002a54;
$secondary-color: #fffeea;
$secondary-highlight: #fffbad;
$black: #000000;
  

@mixin non-mobile {
    @media (min-width: 750px) {
        @content
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that unnecessary re-renders should be avoided. Storing the windowWidth in state every time it changes will cause many re-renders and is not very performant.

A better solution would be to only store the boolean state mobile/non-mobile, as this will only change when you cross the width threshold.

You could adapt your code to look something more like this:

```
function isMobileWidth() {
    return window.innerWidth < 750;
}

function HeaderComponent() {
  (…)

  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(isMobileWidth());

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleWindowResize() {
      setIsMobile(isMobileWidth());
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);
    };
  }, []);

  (...)
}
```

This approach still makes use of the window resize event, but will only cause a re-render when `isMobile` changes.

An even better way of doing it would be to make use of the [Window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) function. This takes in a media query as an argument (as you would use within css) and will only fire an event when the outcome of the media query changes. Unlike the window resize event which is called repeatedly when resizing.

You would write that as so:

```
const mobileMediaQuery = '(max-width: 750px)'   

function HeaderComponent() {
  (…)

  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(window.matchMedia(mobileMediaQuery).matches);

  useEffect(() => {
    
    const query = window.matchMedia(mobileMediaQuery);

    function handleQueryChange(queryEvent) {
      
      /* The matches property will be true if the window width is below the mobile size. */
      setIsMobile(queryEvent.matches);
    }

    query.addEventListener('change', handleQueryChange);

    return () => {
      query.removeEventListener('change', handleQueryChange);
    };
  }, []);

  (...)
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response. I assume you mean window.matchMedia (not watchMedia), right? Running the code, it doesn't seem to call the `handleQueryChange`(added a console.log to track it). Am I still missing something?

Comment: Oops, yes `matchMedia` is correct and I also forgot to add parentheses to the `mobileMediaQuery`! I've edited the code in my answer. With those changes, `isMobile` will toggle as expected. Here's a sandbox to show it in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-solomon-ctc536?file=/src/App.js&resolutionWidth=870&resolutionHeight=675

Comment: Thanks, and no worries about the little typo. It actually helped me learn as I routed through the code. I think we're almost there. It works when I hit the 750px mark, but the menu disappears as soon as the width is larger. I'm guessing we have to say `>=` rather than just `matches` for the `queryEvent`?

Comment: Yep, it works perfectly with `setIsMobile(queryEvent >= mobileMediaQuery);`. Thanks for showing me this neat solution!

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to do the comparison `queryEvent >= mobileMediaQuery` as you are comparing an object to a string, which is meaningless in this case. If you log the `isMobile` value, when using the code in my answer, you will see that it gives the expected value when changing screen width. The reason your menu was disappearing above 750px will be for some other reason.

Comment: Weirdly enough it works beautifully when I do the >= comparison. So not sure what the issue might be that you are pointing at. From what I'm seeing the `.matches` approach only allows for *exactly* 750, nothing above or below – at least how it is reacting in my code.